# Search array of object in treeview and get expanded matched nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create  a react search tree component for which I will supply the data in below format and user will type in input box to search items in search tree.  The matched items should be expanded.    Below is the data.

```
const JSON = [
  {
    label: "Make",
    filters: [
      {
        label: "Year",
        filters: [
          {
            name: 2011,
            value: true
          },
          {
            label: "Month",
            filters: [
              {
                name: "Jan",
                value: false
              },
              {
                name: "Mar",
                value: true
              },
              {
                name: "Aug",
                value: true
              },
              {
                name: "Oct",
                value: false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Type",
        filters: [
          {
            name: "Basic",
            value: true
          },
          {
            label: "Premium",
            filters: [
              {
                name: "Luxury",
                value: true
              },
              {
                name: "Super Luxury",
                value: false
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Sport",
            value: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Year",
    filters: [
      {
        name: 2011,
        value: false
      },
      {
        name: 2012,
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 2013,
        value: false
      },
      {
        name: 2014,
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 2015,
        value: false
      },
      {
        name: 2016,
        value: true
      },
      {
        name: 2017,
        value: false
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

When the user searches from an input control I want to filter the tree view  and supply new array of objects 
With added properties like “isExpanded” and “highlightStr”

```
 searchTree(data) {
    let count = 0;
    let tierCount = 0;
    let isGroup = false;
    data.filters.forEach(filter => {
      if (filter.filters) {

        tierCount = this.searchTree(filter);
     //how can i search here ? and add properties 
     // like isExpanded or highlightStr

      } else {
        if (filter.value) {

        }
      }
    });
    return count;
  }
```

From the above code how could I search the input string.  I am having problem to do this with recursion.

I need the output as entire array of objects with added properties to identify a node is expanded and to highlight matched text

Comment: If you are using recursion, you need to search *before* you call the recursive function. Right now this only runs until this line: `tierCount = this.searchTree(filter);` because it gets called again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but to simply searching for value: true in this tree and assigning new property for that you do something like this:

when more filters available you go deeper but when no more tiers you simply check if value===true and assign new property.

```
function searchTree(data) {
   let count = 0;
   let tierCount = 0;
   let isGroup = false;

   data.filters.forEach(filter => {
      if (filter.filters) {
        tierCount = this.searchTree(filter);
      } 

      if (filter.value) {
        filter.isExpanded = true;
      }
    });

    return count;
}
```

https://codepen.io/mskalniak/pen/QJoJMg

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I need to add the isExpanded Property to the matched parents.  For example if user is searching 201 as he types, then the label make, year should have the isExpanded property